# Given an instance of a Swift object, can we test its class for the presence of a class function?

Tags: swift, class, generics, static, protocols

I've looked around, and haven't seen an answer to my question (but maybe I should be able to infer one).

I have an object, based on a protocol. It's an associated type protocol, with class operators that are defined, based on the type assigned to associatedtype, like so:

```
protocol GenericBaseProtocol {
    associatedtype T

    var myProperty: T {get set}
    init(_ myProperty: T )
}

extension GenericBaseProtocol where T: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.myProperty == rhs.myProperty
    }
}
```

So if I create a class, based on this, and give T an Equatable type, like so:

```
class IntClass: GenericBaseProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
    var myProperty: T = 0

    required init(_ myProperty: T ) {
        self.myProperty = myProperty
    }
}
```

The resulting object should be comparable, like so:

```
let lhs = IntClass(3)
let rhs = IntClass(4)

let isEqual = lhs == rhs
```

Cool. Now, if I then create an instance with a non-Equatable type, like so:

```
class ArrayClass: GenericBaseProtocol {
    typealias T = [String]
    var myProperty: T = []

    required init(_ myProperty: T ) {
        self.myProperty = myProperty
    }
}
```

And instantiate that, like so:

```
let lhs2A = ArrayClass(["HI"])
let rhs2A = ArrayClass(["Howaya"])
```

I will have compile-time syntax errors when I try this:

```
let isEqual = lhs2A == rhs2A
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is test the class object of lhs2A, and see if it implements static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool

I'm not sure this can be done, but it would be nice for this article I'm writing up if I could add a runtime/guard proof to the playground, instead of simply commenting out the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's not equatable you can't use `==`. The compiler has already done its work. There is nothing to check.

Comment: Yup. I know that. I am writing up an article that demonstrates this. I tend to comment out compiler errors like that, but I wanted to know if there's any way to catch the issue in runtime, since it does allow you to define the class, and only pukes when you try to use it inappropriately.

Comment: There isn't any "issue at runtime". The compiler prevents it from ever arising.

Comment: Yeah. I know. I don't want to write the bad code. I want to prove that the instance that was created does not have the same undercarriage as the one that was created from the same protocol, but assigning an Equatable type. It isn't a big deal. I'll just add commented-out code, but it would have been slick to be able to simply have a guard that prints out a "This instance doesn't have an equality test".

Comment: I don't see why it "would have been slick". It would have been a disaster. Swift uses static typing. If you want the ability to crash and burn because something doesn't implement something and snuck by the compiler, use Objective-C or Ruby etc.

Comment: Not really. I'm writing an article on associated type protocols. I wanted to give a demonstration on how the compiler works, "under the hood." I always provide a big playground to go with the articles I write, and I usually have lots of commented out "what not to do" things. I could add a commented out  let isEqual = lhs2A == rhs2A, but it would be more instructive to have a print of a message, declaring the two classes to have a fundamental structural difference (that would result in a compiler error), but I would like to do it without pooching the whole playground.

Comment: You might be interested in https://academy.realm.io/posts/goto-mike-ash-exploring-swift-memory-layout/

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend your protocol to give it a default implementation for the == operator in cases where the associated type is not Equatable.

This could also be used to provide a runtime indicator of wether the type is equatable or not.

for example:

```
extension GenericBaseProtocol where T: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.myProperty == rhs.myProperty
    }
    var isEquatable:Bool { return true }
}

extension GenericBaseProtocol {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    var isEquatable:Bool { return false }
}
```

Comment: Hey! That's not a bad idea! I'll see if I  can work something up along those lines.

Comment: I added your example to the sample playground in [my post](https://littlegreenviper.com/series/swiftwater/associated_type/). Great suggestion!